# Отменить асинхронное выполнение SqlCommand

Tags: c#, async-await

Предположим есть

```
SqlCommand сmd = ...
```

которая может долго исполняться. Команда вызывается асинхронно, и для возможности отмены в метод Execute передаётся `CancellationToken`.

Достаточно ли только передавать `CancellationToken`:

```
await сmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
```

или лучше делать

```
using (cancellationToken.Register(() => { сmd.Cancel(); }))
    await сmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Есть ли разница? (Срабатывает вроде бы одинаково).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно первого метода. [Документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204860%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) обещает, что `cancellationToken` будет работать без дополнительных заклинаний:

> The cancellation token can be used to request that the operation be abandoned before the command timeout elapses.

Во втором методе вы отменяете команду сами, по сути при этом `cancellationToken` внутри `ExecuteNonQueryAsync` вовсе не нужен. (Да и потенциально возможны проблемы с многопоточностью, зачем вам они?)

Заметьте, что обрыв команды по `Cancel` не гарантирует *остановки* команды, если она уже реально запущена (это зависит от внутренностей работы с конкретной базой данных), а только то, что её результат будет игнорироваться.

---

Обновление: Если посмотреть исходники BCL, внутри метода 
[`ExecuteNonQueryAsync`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,844820896a87b3a7) делается именно подписка на cancellation у токена (только чуть более экономно):

```
if (cancellationToken.CanBeCanceled) {
    // если нас уже отменили. можно и не начинать (VladD)
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) {
        source.SetCanceled();
        return source.Task;
    }
    registration = cancellationToken.Register(CancelIgnoreFailure);
}
```

где [`CancelIgnoreFailure`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DBCommand.cs,9dfee6f630bba1f9) — вызывает `Cancel()`:

```
internal void CancelIgnoreFailure() {
    // This method is used to route CancellationTokens to the Cancel method.
    // Cancellation is a suggestion, and exceptions should be ignored
    // rather than allowed to be unhandled, as there is no way to route
    // them to the caller.  It would be expected that the error will be
    // observed anyway from the regular method.  An example is cancelling
    // an operation on a closed connection.
    try
    {
        Cancel();
    } catch(Exception) {
        // Cancel может привести к исключению, ловим его (VladD)
    }
}
```

Таким образом, самостоятельно подписывается на `cancellationToken` не нужно.